# Why can Java apps/applets be decompiled?

Tags: java, android, applet, reverse-engineering

I have been working on some Android apps recently and am slightly frustrated that my apps can be reverse engineered. I do obsfucate my code but that can only go so far, a talented developer can easily get around the obsfucation.

Anyway, my question is this, why can Java app's be decompiled ? What part of Java's design allows its app's to be decompiled?

My understanding is that Java apps deploy JIT compilation, so they are only compiled before they are used for efficiency purposes, is this correct ? I would love to know the reason,

thanks!

Comment: It's not a reason.  Any compiled language can be decompiled.  If A + B = C, the  C - B = A.

Comment: If a Java class *couldn't* be decompiled, how could the VM *run* it? (Even code compiled to ML must be *understood* by the CPU.) Note that obfuscation is different from compilation: obfuscation is designed to make the decompiled compiled output *less friendly* for humans (i.e. identifier/code mangling). Machines don't care - and neither will someone who really wants to see *how* something is done.

Comment: then why can't the same be done for iOS apps ?

Comment: @rusty009 The exact same can be done for iOS. iOS code is [almost] always Objective-C which uses high-level objects that expose "message names" in decompiled output. This makes it easier to "understand" when decompiled than stripped C, and similar in nature to Java. Now, for tooling - I suspect there is more tooling designed to reverse-engineer Java, but the process is the same.

Comment: why the vote downs ?!?

Comment: Because it's a meaningless question based on a false assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Anyway, my question is this, why can Java app's be decompiled ?

Any app, in any language, can be decompiled. That should be obvious to anyone with a smattering of programming experience in a compiled programming language.

A compiler takes bytes and creates a different set of bytes that represents the same set of instructions. A decompiler takes bytes and creates a different set of bytes that represents the same set of instructions. The difference is merely in what those bytes are. A compiler takes bytes that are (relatively) human readable and creates bytes that are (relatively) machine readable. A decompiler does the reverse.

How *well* a given decompiler can do its job, though, depends on the programming language and the implementation of the decompiler itself.

In the case of a language like C, the compiler generates machine instructions for a CPU. Those can be readily decompiled into assembly language, as assembler instructions map fairly closely 1:1 to machine instructions. A sufficiently sophisticated decompiler can emit C as output, though probably not C that would be natural to write. More importantly, the decompiled output will largely use decompiler-generated names for functions and variables, unless the compiled C code has debug symbols, in which case the decompiler might be able to use those.

A language like Java is not significantly different in concept. While Java or Dalvik bytecode is for a VM rather than a CPU, the basic approach is the same. Obfuscation helps to ensure that the minimum number of human-readable symbols exist in the resulting bytecode, to reduce the legibility of any decompiled results. Also, the mapping of VM bytecode to language statements tends to be far closer than the mapping of machine code to C statements, which makes it easier to write a decompiler that gives you closer to Java syntax back (e.g., smali/baksmali).

It is the degree of difficulty in interpreting decompiled machine code that results in recommendations to move license management logic into native code via the NDK, for example. However, that is not to say that the results of a C compiler cannot be decompiled at all.

Comment: The take-away is that there is pretty much nothing that can be done in order to make natively run code impossible for someone to decompile and understand.  If you really don't want someone to be able to understand the logic behind the application, the only thing to do is never distribute that code (run it on your server and use a RESTful API or something).  Even hardware is not immune to decompiling (reverse engineering), as there is always going to be someone smart enough to take a finished product and figure out how it was constructed.  Practically, this is inefficient though.

Comment: @Dazedy: "If you really don't want someone to be able to understand the logic behind the application, the only thing to do is never distribute that code" -- agreed. The same holds true for data: if you don't want users to have access to "your" data, don't put it on their device.

Comment: One of the main causes of security / data breaches is that information was put in an insufficiently secure environment.  IE: It doesn't matter how many passwords you put on your laptop, if you leave on your porch at night, chances are someone will take it.  Information is even harder to be careful about, due to the way that things are interconnected.